# Is there any way to keep the index.js/ts file at the top of the file stack in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's kind of bad to find the index.js file among several files of the same type, is there any way to keep it always at the top or always at the bottom?

I looked for extensions but none do this, I also couldn't find them in the vscode settings